# Flink evenly distributes the required slots across all Task Managers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, taskmanager, flink-batch

I have two different tasks in my flink job Task1 & Task2.
T1 needs 10 Parrelisms and T2 needs 2 parrallism, my cluster has two Taskmanager(TM) and each of my task managers have 8 slots.
Task1 runs with default task groups and for Task 2 I m setting separate slot-sharing group

Since I had requirements to distribute my talks sots across TM evenly, I added a cluster. **evenly-spread-out-slots: true** and deploy my application but evenly distributed is not working.
Task manager 1 runs 8 (2 from Task2 and 6 from Task1) and Taskmanager 2 runs 4.

My requirement is each task manager should run 6 (5 for Task1 and 1 for Task2)

FOr testing, whether **evenly-spread-out-slots: true** work runs or not I commented out  Task1 and submitted Task2, with this I can see Task2 runs on both TM1 and TM2 with 1 slot each.

Is there any setting to make sure evenly distributions happen for both the task groups?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with even slots distribution and ended up utilizing the [Fine-Grained Resource Management](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/finegrained_resource/).

So, in your case, let's assume that each task manager has 6Gb RAM and 6 cores, for example. Then, in order to have exactly 5 slots for `task-1` slot-sharing group per-tm and exactly 1 slot for `task-2` slot sharing group per-tm, I used mutual exclusive requirements:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

SlotSharingGroup ssgTask1 = SlotSharingGroup.newBuilder("task-1")
  .setCpuCores(1.1)
  .setTaskHeapMemoryMB(10)
  .build();

SlotSharingGroup ssgTask2 = SlotSharingGroup.newBuilder("task-2")
  .setCpuCores(0.1)
  .setTaskHeapMemoryMB(5900)
  .build();
```

With this specification, `task-2` slot sharing group requires slot with `5900MB` heap, which almost occupies all the task manager capacity and therefore each task manager is able to allocate at most 1 `task-2` slot.

Similarly, `task-1` slot sharing group requires `1.1` cpu cores, so with 6 cores in total per-tm, each tm is able to allocate at most 5 `task-1` slots.

With this slot sharing groups configuration I always get even slot sharing group slots distribution across all task managers.

Comment: That's a clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

With `evenly-spread-out-slots: false`

- the scheduler will take slots from TM1 until none remain, and then move on to TM2

With `evenly-spread-out-slots: true`

- the scheduler will take slots from the least used TM when there aren’t any other preferences
- sources don't have preferences
- the rest of the topology will follow, with consumers preferring to be co-located with their producers

I not sure it's possible to achieve what you're trying to do. But have you tried this without putting task 2 into a separate slot-sharing group?

Comment: Yes, Task1 get  distributes evenly but both slots of task2 is  running on the same taskmanager